# Can I change to a custom conference once an NCAA Football 11 Online Dynasty has been created?

Tags: ncaa-football-11, xbox-360

I created an Online Dynasty in NCAA Football 11, intending for all participants to join using SEC teams. However, players now want to move other teams into the conference. I can rearrange the schedule, but I can't find any option (in the game or on the website) to change the conference. We're still in preseason - no games have been played yet.

Is it possible to adjust conference members once a dynasty is created, or is my only option to delete and recreate the dynasty? If so, it's not a big deal, I'd just rather not deal with the cat-herding involved in getting my degenerate friends to finish picking teams before creating the new dynasty.

Comment: thanks for the ncaa-footall-11 tag, didn't have enough rep to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no - created a new dynasty to see where the option for a custom conference was available, and then compared it to my existing dynasty. The option wasn't available.